# Simple comparator does not sort as (I) expected

Tags: clojure

I expected this code snippet to produce the original vector, but sorted in a case-insensitive way. Instead I get the original vector untouched. Why doesn't my comparator work?

```
user=> (ns user (require [clojure.contrib.string :as str]))
nil
user=> (sort 
         (comparator #(compare (str/upper-case %1) (str/upper-case %2)))
         ["B" "a" "c" "F" "r" "E"])
("B" "a" "c" "F" "r" "E")
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`comparator` returns a `java.util.Comparator` when given a predicate (a function which returns true or false). You don't need it if you're using `compare` explicitly. So just:

```
(sort #(compare (str/upper-case %1) (str/upper-case %2))
      ["B" "a" "c" "F" "r" "E"])
;=> ("a" "B" "c" "E" "F" "r")
```

Alternatively, use `sort-by`:

```
(sort-by str/upper-case ["B" "a" "c" "F" "r" "E"])
;=> ("a" "B" "c" "E" "F" "r")
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was confused by the fact that comparators produce 3 possible values (-1, 0, 1) and predicates can produce just true or false. So it seems you never get 0 from something that was made using (comparator).

Comment: Erm, spoke too soon, (comparator) **does** actually handle equality as well.

Answer (score 1):

compare is not a predicate, it's a comparator.